# Can one buy or rent a vacation home during the 12 months of mourning?

Tags: transactions, mourning-aveilus, home-house

[This source](http://www.jewishpathways.com/files/Mourning_(Post-Burial).pdf) says:

> During the twelve months (of mourning for a parent), it is forbidden to:
>
> purchase or rent a home, unless a significant loss would otherwise be
>   incurred

Does "home" mean a permanent year-round residence only? Or does this prohibition include buying or renting a vacation home where one will stay for a week or a few months during the year?

Comment: I highly doubt that it's talking about _davka_ buying a house. Probably any large purchase would be included here. The article cites _sefer yesodei s'machot_ which I don't have access to and cannot find online, but that may be a good place to look.

Comment: @Daniel I'm unfamiliar with this Sefer, but, perhaps hebrewbooks has it. I'm also puzzled by the phrasing "significant loss". How can you lose something that you haven't yet owned?

Comment: I didn't see it on HebrewBooks. I believe there is a debate among modern _poskim_ about whether missing out on an opportunity to make a lot of money (or even save a lot of money) counts as an economic loss. According to one side, if the price of the house will go up (or if you won't be able to get it if you wait), that may count as a significant loss (consult your rabbi). Alternatively, perhaps if you don't move houses, you're going to have some huge tax bills coming up.

Comment: I guess that if it is in Israel it is permitted

Answer (score 1):

[Chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/371240/jewish/The-Shloshim.htm) brings the law of not buying a house in the context of “activities that are not in the spirit of mourning”. It speaks about sheloshim for other relatives but it applies to parents for the whole 12-month period.

> One should avoid activities that are not in the spirit of mourning.
>   For example, one may not buy a new home, nor redecorate, renovate, or
>   purchase new furniture, and so on, unless one will suffer great
>   financial loss if it is delayed past the Shloshim.

The question then is whether renting a vacation home where one will stay for a week or a few months during the year is  in the spirit of mourning.

I could not find an answer to that question but did find at [dinonline](http://dinonline.org/2015/08/07/vacation-during-aveilus/) regarding a vacation to recuperate the following (but I could not find the sources mentioned)

> See Shulchan Aruch Y:D 389:25, the Aruch Hashulchan [seif 33] explains
>   that only travelling with large groups which makes a pronounce festive
>   atmosphere should be avoided during this time. A personal trip to
>   recuperate is permitted.

The implication is that if there is no pronounced festive atmosphere then renting the holiday home should be allowed.

Comment: The implication sounds fine to me. *Tzarich iyun*. (Needs further research.)

Answer (score -1):

If the house will not be available for the same price after the mourning then you may buy it during the mourning period, unless after the mourning period the price gets lower not higher.

Comment: Hi Max. How do you know this? Without any sources for your claim, we have no reason to take your word for it. After all, none of us know you.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. See the text of the question which already says, "unless a significant loss would otherwise be incurred". Essentially, you've defined the phrasing in the question.